# Substring dynaminc location points in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my data from select query, how can i dynamically extract point into two separate column latitude and longitude?

Point is nvarchar.

```
Aliwal North    POINT(27.362284919999997 -30.52445202)
Aliwal North    POINT(27.37309788 -30.528905039999998)
Brits           POINT(27.31393692 -25.612940969999997)
Brits           POINT(27.235719 -25.66400301)
Brits           POINT(27.77974596 -25.64028801)
Cape Town       POINT(18.50227992 -33.96229002) 
Cape Town       POINT(18.4633397797679 -33.9180458589211)   
Durban          POINT(31.004268839999998 -29.855645009999996)
Durban          POINT(30.88134216 -29.91320703)
Durban          POINT(30.989153159999997 -29.783537009999996)
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like valid geography data. Simply use the provided [geography support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/spatial-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017).

```
declare @t table(name varchar(50), location_text nvarchar(200))
insert into @t(name, location_text) values
('Aliwal North',    'POINT(27.362284919999997 -30.52445202)'),
('Aliwal North',    'POINT(27.37309788 -30.528905039999998)'),
('Brits       ',    'POINT(27.31393692 -25.612940969999997)'),
('Brits       ',    'POINT(27.235719 -25.66400301)'),
('Brits       ',    'POINT(27.77974596 -25.64028801)'),
('Cape Town   ',    'POINT(18.50227992 -33.96229002) '),
('Cape Town   ',    'POINT(18.4633397797679 -33.9180458589211) '),  
('Durban      ',    'POINT(31.004268839999998 -29.855645009999996)'),
('Durban      ',    'POINT(30.88134216 -29.91320703)'),
('Durban      ',    'POINT(30.989153159999997 -29.783537009999996)')

select
    name
    , geography::STGeomFromText(location_text, 4326).STStartPoint().Long as Longitude
    , geography::STGeomFromText(location_text, 4326).STStartPoint().Lat as Latitude
from @t
```

Or use CROSS APPLY to parse the data only once:

```
select
    name
    , Location.StartingPoint.Long as Longitude
    , Location.StartingPoint.Lat as Latitude
from @t
cross apply (select geography::STGeomFromText(location_text, 4326).STStartPoint() as StartingPoint) Location
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use combination of `charindex` with `substring` as

```
   select substring(q.latitude,pr1+1,len(q.latitude)) as latitude,
          substring(q.longitude,1,len(q.longitude)-1) as longitude
     from
       (
        select substring(Point, 1, charindex(' ', Point) - 1)
               as latitude,
               substring(Point, charindex(' ', Point)+1,  len(Point))
               as longitude,
               charindex('(',substring(Point, 1, charindex(' ', Point) - 1)) as pr1,
               charindex(')',substring(Point, charindex(' ', Point)+1,  len(Point))) as pr2
          from Points
       ) q;

        latitude             longitude
   ------------------   -------------------
   27.362284919999997   -30.52445202
   27.37309788          -30.528905039999998
   ............         ...........
   ............         ...........
```

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/ZOS57185)

Comment: Thanks guys, especially Barbaros Ozhan i used CharIndex with Substring

Comment: @LateBloomer you're welcome friend. If it helped, kindly please mark the answer :)